# Scan/Record application's outgoing IP requests?

Tags: ip

How can I scan/record IP requests from a specific application or task? Could I do this purely in command line or is extra software required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) is a very powerful tool for tracing connections and even examining packet content. By using the appropriate filters you can monitor all network activity of your application.